# Using web-components within Preact and typescript

Tags: typescript, web-component, custom-element, preact

I'm using [custom-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements) aka web-components within [Preact](https://preactjs.com/). The problem is that Typescript complains about elements not being defined in `JSX.IntrinsicElements` - in this case a `check-box` element:

```html
<div className={styles.option}>
    <check-box checked={this.prefersDarkTheme} ref={this.svgOptions.darkTheme}/>
    <p>Dark theme</p>
</div>
```

Error message (path omitted):

```
ERROR in MyComponent.tsx
[tsl] ERROR in MyComponent.tsx(50,29)
      TS2339: Property 'check-box' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.
```

I came across the following, unfortunately not working, possible solutions:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57449556/7664765 *- It's an answer not really realted to the question but it covered my problem*

I've tried adding the following to my `typings.d.ts` file:

```js
import * as Preact from 'preact';

declare global {
    namespace JSX {
        interface IntrinsicElements {
            'check-box': any; // The 'any' just for testing purposes
        }
    }
}
```

My IDE grayed out the import part and `IntrinsicElements` which means it's not used (?!) and it didn't worked anyway. I'm still getting the same error message.

2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55424778/7664765 *- Also for react, I've tried to "convert" it to preact and I got the same results as for 1.*

I've even found a [file](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/squoosh/blob/master/src/custom-els/RangeInput/missing-types.d.ts) maintained by google in the [squoosh](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/squoosh) project where they did the following to "polyfill" the support:

> In the same folder as the component a `missing-types.d.ts` file with the following content, basically the same setup I have but with a `index.ts` file instead of `check-bock.ts` and they're using an older TS version `v3.5.3`:

```js
declare namespace JSX {
  interface IntrinsicElements {
    'range-input': HTMLAttributes;
  }
}
```

I'm assuming their build didn't fail so how does it work and how do I properly define custom-elements to use them within preact / react components?

I'm currently using `typescript@v3.8.3` and `preact@10.3.4`.

Answer (score 6):

Here are the correct attributes to use, otherwise you will get an error when passing `key` in for example.

```js
declare global {
  namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicElements {
      'xx-element1': React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>; // Normal web component
      'xx-element2': React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>; // Web component extended from input
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Okay I managed to solve it using [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation):

```
declare module 'preact/src/jsx' {
    namespace JSXInternal {

        // We're extending the IntrinsicElements interface which holds a kv-list of
        // available html-tags.
        interface IntrinsicElements {
            'check-box': unknown;
        }
    }
}
```

Using the `HTMLAttributes` interface we can tell JSX which attributes are available for our custom-element:

```
// Your .ts file, e.g. index.ts
declare module 'preact/src/jsx' {
    namespace JSXInternal {
        import HTMLAttributes = JSXInternal.HTMLAttributes;

        interface IntrinsicElements {
            'check-box': HTMLAttributes<CheckBoxElement>;
        }
    }
}

// This interface describes our custom element, holding all its
// available attributes. This should be placed within a .d.ts file.
declare interface CheckBoxElement extends HTMLElement {
    checked: boolean;
}
```

Comment: This is the one, future self.

Comment: Wow, yep, here I am again. Wish I could upvote this answer multiple times.

Answer (score 5):

With typescript 4.2.3 and preact 10.5.13, here is what works to define a custom tag name with attributes:

```
declare module 'preact' {
    namespace JSX {
        interface IntrinsicElements {
            'overlay-trigger': OverlayTriggerAttributes;
        }
    }
}

interface OverlayTriggerAttributes extends preact.JSX.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement> {
    placement?: string;
}
```

Differences:

- The module is `'preact'` (must be quoted).
- The namespace is `JSX`.
- The `IntrinsicElements` value type is an interface that extends HTMLAttributes.
- It extends HTMLAttributes via the name `preact.JSX.HTMLAttributes`.
- It supplies the base element type as `HTMLElement` to populate the eventTarget type in props/attrs like event listeners. You could also put `SVGElement` if applicable.

Comment: This works for me with TypeScript 4.3.5 and Preact 10.5.15, with the caveat that I also needed to `import 'preact'` before my declaration.

Comment: THIS IS THE ONE! THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way to do this without manually binding events.

You can use `@lit-labs/react`'s `createComponent` to wrap web component to React Component.

```js
import * as React from "react";

import { createComponent } from "@lit-labs/react";
import Slrange from "@shoelace-style/shoelace/dist/components/range/range.js";

export const Range = createComponent(React, "sl-range", Slrange,{
    change: "sl-change" // map web component event to react event
});
```

```js
import { Range } from "./SlRange";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Range max={6} min={2} step={2}></Range>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-web-component]

Comment: It is still a web component under the hood just abstacted

Comment: I like this but it's not for Preact