# jsx.intrinsicelements does not exist 2339 when using custom-element

Tags: typescript, jsx, lit-element

I've created a custom-element with lit 2.0 (using typescript)

```
import {LitElement, html, css} from 'lit';
import {customElement, property} from 'lit/decorators.js';

export class VVButton extends LitElement {

  render() {
    return html`
      <button style="background-color: red;"><slot></slot></button>
    `;
  }
}

customElements.define('vv-button', VVButton);
```

I've uploaded to private npm package.. the code is compiled and tested on html file and all is good.

I tried to import the package on existing project which also using Typescript, see below my file:

```
import '@vv-web-components/button-tmp';

const ProjectsActions = (): JSX.Element => {
    const options: IconOption[] = [
        { id: 'find', ariaLabel: 'Find', icon: <Magnify /> },
        { id: 'sort', ariaLabel: 'Sort', icon: <ArrowDown /> },
    ];

    return (
        <Flex marginY={'auto'} direction={'row'}>
            <Options iconOptions={options} />
            <NewProjectDialog buttonText={'Create new project'} />
            <vv-button>click here</vv-button>
        </Flex>
    );
};

export default ProjectsActions;
```

The thing is that I got error when using `<vv-button>click here</vv-button>`
The `import '@vv-web-components/button-tmp'` is the npm package (private package).

the error is

```
Property 'vv-button' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.ts(2339)
```

how can I fix it ?

---

Edit/ Progress update:
I took @aleksxor advice, and added global declare on the website code (not in package), it's not OK - I don't want to add workarounds on my code (package code will be OK)
see this is how it looks now:

```
import {LitElement, html, css} from 'lit';
import {customElement, property} from 'lit/decorators.js';
   
export class VVButton extends LitElement {

  render() {
    return html`
      <button style="background-color: red; width: 50px; height: 30px;"></button>
    `;
  }
}
```

and in my website code:

```
import '@vv-web-components/button-tmp'

declare global {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-namespace
    namespace JSX {
        interface IntrinsicElements extends HTMLElement {
            // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
            'vv-button': React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>; 
        }
    }
}

const ProjectsActions = (): JSX.Element => {
    const options: IconOption[] = [
        { id: 'find', ariaLabel: 'Find', icon: <Magnify /> },
        { id: 'sort', ariaLabel: 'Sort', icon: <ArrowDown /> },
    ];

    return (
        <Flex marginY={'auto'} direction={'row'}>
            <Options iconOptions={options} />
            <NewProjectDialog buttonText={'Create new project'} />
            <vv-button>Button Text</vv-button>
        </Flex>
    );
};

export default ProjectsActions;
```

This works partially, the "Button Text" doesn't displayed in the button!
and as I said above, I can't add this declare in my website code.. is there a way to add it in the package code ?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62934334/3388225) answers your question?

Comment: @aleksxor  should I add the declare global on same VVButton class ?

Comment: I believe including type definition with this declaration into your package should fix the issue.

Comment: @aleksxor I edit my post, please take a look